# How can I connect drupal 6 and activemq?

Tags: 6

I would like to use publish subscribe technique to send updates to drupal as they happen in an external database. This database has middleware that publishes changes using a messaging system (apache camel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to upgrade to Drupal 7, [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) version 3 should interface to (for instance) [JSON](http://camel.apache.org/json.html) or [SOAP](http://camel.apache.org/soap.html).

Feature of version 3:

> - Response format API allows you to define response Formats for CONTENT-TYPE ie. `application/json` or `application/xml`.

Edit: I didn't know about [STOMP](http://drupal.org/project/stomp), which the OP mentions in a comment. I add it here for searches/future reference:

> STOMP is the Simple (or Streaming) Text Orientated Messaging Protocol. The Stomp module implements an alternative Drupal Queue backend for queues supporting the STOMP protocol - such as ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ.

For Drupal 6, there is [JSON server](http://drupal.org/project/json_server).  I am not familiar with it, but you may be able to use that instead.

Comment: It is drupal-6  - was looking at 'stomp' module in drupal-7 but it would take me 2 times the budget to upgrade the site to 7. I could poll every 2 minutes for changes using JSON but it is a poor fit to the problem. The existing JSON interfaces don't use the services module as consuming them is 3 lines of code - perhaps this means I am not focused on what services can do.

Comment: Backporting STOMP is currently what I am looking at. I thought tag '6' was discouraged - sorry.